# Html Beginform with button click is not working in .net core mvc

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

Below is my registration form razor page

```
<div class="reg-panels">
    <div class="container-rim">
        <div class="row-fluid clearfix">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <h2>
                    Please enter your account information
                </h2>
                <div class="register-accounts">
                    <h3>
                        @strMemTypeText Membership - @strMemPlanText
                    </h3>
                    @using (Html.BeginForm())
                     {
                        <table>
                            <tr>
                                <td class="FormLeft" width="200px">
                                    <span class="mandtry">* </span>Username:
                                </td>
                                <td class="FormRight">
                                    @Html.TextBoxFor(u => u.UserName, new { @class = "form-control", @Placeholder = "UserName", @onkeypress = "return AvoidSpace(event)" })
                                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(u => u.UserName, "", new { @class = "red" })
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td colspan="2" align="center">
                                    <input type="submit" class="btn" id="btnProceed" value="Proceed"/>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>

                     }
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

My controller.cs

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult RegisterStep(Company company)
{
    .....
}
```

When I click the proceed button no action is done.
Also i tried using **@using (Html.BeginForm("Action","controller", FormMethod.Post))**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a demo worked,you need to make sure your controller name and action name are right:

View:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Home", FormMethod.Post))
{
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td class="FormLeft" width="200px">
                <span class="mandtry">* </span>Username:
            </td>
            <td class="FormRight">
                <input name="username" />
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2" align="center">
                <input type="submit" class="btn" id="btnProceed" value="Proceed" />
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>

}
```

HomeController:

```
public IActionResult Index(string username)
        {
            return View();
        }
```

If you don't work,do you have any error message in your Console or NetWork?
[image]

Comment: Hi Yiyi You, Thanks for your reply. Yeah some issues displayed in network console related to username validation in java scripts..

Comment: Can you share the message in your console

Comment: Thanks Yiyi You... The reason is i am not adding the validation controller. After adding the controller it works fine.

Answer (score 1):

Your code looks good but you may check

1. Validation Part if you cleared required validation string. And you'r trying to pass empty data.
2. Open developer console and check if any error in console part.
3. Remove '@' from placeholder and javascript event call(not sure)